# K3s agent node not getting connected to master node on AWS Instance

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, rancher, k3s

**Environmental Info:**
K3s Version:
v1.23.8+k3s1 (53f2d4e7)

**Node(s) CPU architecture:** OS, and Version:
Linux ip-172-31-88-240 5.15.0-1011-aws #14-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 1 20:54:22 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Cluster Configuration:**
1 master and 2 agent nodes

**Description  the bug:**
Agent node not joining master node when I type command kubectl get nodes.

**Steps To Reproduce:**

- **Installed K3s on the master node**

  - $ `MASTER_IP=3.93.220.207 (IPv4 Public IP: 3.93.220.207)`

```
$curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="--write-kubeconfig-mode 644 --no-deploy traefik --disable traefik --tls-san "$MASTER_IP" --node-external-ip "$MASTER_IP" --disable servicelb" sh -s -
```

Generated token by  sudo cat /var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/node-token

**On each agent**

```
MASTER_IP=3.93.220.207
export TOKEN=YOUR_MASTER_TOKEN 
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -s - agent --server https://$MASTER_IP :6443 --token ${TOKEN}
```

**Expected behavior:**
`kubectl get nodes` command should show agent nodes, but agent nodes are not attached ...

[image: Screenshot 2022-07-04 at 2 51 39 PM]

**Actual behavior:**
kubectl get nodes does not show agent nodes ....

Please help me to resolve this issue ..... I have done all steps correctly and also exposed the public IP ....I am feeling frustated ... I have been trying this from many days.I even tried implementing this on a virtual box as well but every time I get disappointment.

**EXTRA INFORMATION**
(failed to get CA CERTS)

`systemctl status k3s-agent` command gives shows [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your master node setup command, since you did not supply `K3S_TOKEN` so the token is generated, so make sure your `YOUR_MASTER_TOKEN` value is correct, it can be retrieved by running `sudo cat /var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/token` in the master node.

The command you run in K3S agent doesn't look right, it is seems that you are mixing the command of joining cluster as `agent` and as `master`, make sure you know the difference between a HA cluster and non-HA cluster.

To add K3s **agent** to the cluster, just run

```
export URL="https://<<Master IP address>>:6443"
export TOKEN="<<TOKEN>>"
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_URL=$URL K3S_TOKEN=$TOKEN sh -
```

Finally, as you are running it in AWS, make sure your `VPC` settings correct, it includes the right `Security Group` settings to allow communication to/from `IP range` and `Port range` between your `master` and `agent` node. Also, the `NACL` of your subnets.

If you are doing it for POC purpose, just put all the instance in the same `public subnet` will save your time.